# Android Online transaction with API Gateway

Tags: android

Friends,
     I am working to implement online purchasing with credit card,how can i implement it by using third party **API gateway**,or else is there any other best way to implement the same.
Let me have sample code to implement for the same.

Looking for your valuable answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use PAYPAL integration for that.Try this.

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile

https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-2532